# How to store a DOM node into a variable like jQuery does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

In `jQuery` we can store a node in a variable like so: `variable = $(.element)` then manipulate the node through that variable: `variable.hide()`

Can we do this in ES6? It would look like this:

```
var variable = document.querySelector('.portfolio').style.display = 'block'
variable.style.display = 'none'
```

Except that this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to do 2 different things in 1 line of code. First assign the element to a variable and then you can use the variable to modify the style, see my code snippet below.

```js
// First assign the element to a variable
var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');
// Then use the variable to modify the elements style
myElement.style['background-color']='red';
```

```html
<div id="myElement">element</div>
```